# Spring Integration - AMQP Inferred Types In Java DSL?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have been working on a "paved road" for setting up asynchronous messaging between two micro services using AMQP. We want to promote the use of separate domain objects for each service, which means that each service must define their own copy of any objects passed across the queue.

We are using `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` on both the producer and the consumer side and we are using the Java DSL to wire the flows to/from the queues.

I am sure there is a way to do this, but it is escaping me: I want the consumer side to ignore the `__TypeID__` header that is passed from the producer, as the consumer may have a different representation of that event (and it will likely be in in a different java package).

It appears there was work done such that if using the annotation `@RabbitListener`, an `inferredArgumentType`argument is derived and will override the header information. This is exactly what I would like to do, but I would like to use the Java DSL to do it. I have not yet found a clean way in which to do this and maybe I am just missing something obvious. It seems it would be fairly straight forward to derive the type when using the following DSL:

```
return IntegrationFlows
        .from(
                Amqp.inboundAdapter(factory, queueRemoteTaskStatus())
                        .concurrentConsumers(10)
                        .errorHandler(errorHandler)
                        .messageConverter(messageConverter)
        )
        .channel(channelRemoteTaskStatusIn())
        .handle(listener, "handleRemoteTaskStatus")
        .get();
```

However, this results in a `ClassNotFound` exception. The only way I have found to get around this, so far, is to set a custom message converter, which requires explicit definition of the type.

```
public class ForcedTypeJsonMessageConverter extends Jackson2JsonMessageConverter {

    ForcedTypeJsonMessageConverter(final Class<?> forcedType) {
        setClassMapper(new ClassMapper() {

            @Override
            public void fromClass(Class<?> clazz, MessageProperties properties) {
                    //this class is only used for inbound marshalling.
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> toClass(MessageProperties properties) {
                return forcedType;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I would really like this to be derived, so the developer does not have to really deal with this.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I am missing something, but I don't see how it is so "straight forward" in that flow definition to derive  the type? Thanks

Comment: Use type id mapping (`setIdClassMapping`) in the converter's type mapper. See my answer.

Comment: I guess "straight forward" is the wrong term, I am looking for implicit handling of types if the content-type is application/json without having to explicitly define a mapping strategy for specific types. This is a similar idea to the one discussed here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/156. If I remove the typeId on the producer side, and just leave the application/json, it would be nice to get "out of the box" marshaling.

Comment: How can the type be implicit in a messaging flow? With `@RabbitListener` we know the type of the method parameter. When creating a generic message with the inbound payload there is no way to infer the type of the payload since the component creating the message is completely decoupled from the method that consumes the message. Hence, you have to configure the converter with some kind of hint for the payload type. I added another option to my answer.

Comment: Thank makes total sense, thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to configure the Jackson converter's `DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper` with `TypeIdMapping` (`setIdClassMapping()`).

On the sending system, map `foo:com.one.Foo` and on the receiving system map `foo:com.two.Foo`.

Then, the `__TypeId__` header gets `foo` and the receiving system will map it to its representation of a `Foo`.

**EDIT**

Another option would be to add an `afterReceiveMessagePostProcessor` to the inbound channel adapter's listener container - it could change the `__TypeId__` header.